# What probability distribution represents the maximum of multiple of the same normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Given a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, if we define a new distribution $M_n$ based on the maximum of $n$ random samples from the normal distribution $N$, what formula represents $M_n$. I'm certain the increasing the value of $n$ will continue to increase both $M$'s mean as well as decrease its variance, with diminishing returns for both, I'm also pretty certain that all $M_n$ will be normal distributions, but I remain unsure about how to model the distribution of the $M$'s.

Comment: No $M_n$ for $n\geqslant2$ is normal. All your other questions are solved by the remark that, for every $x$, $$P(M_n\leqslant x)=P(X_1\leqslant x)^n=\Phi((x-\mu)/\sigma)^n$$

Comment: Huh. I'm not totally familiar with notation what does $\Phi$ represent in this context?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm thinking about your answer, and I don't think I was clear, what I was trying to ask about is if, for example $M_3$, I randomly generate 3 number, $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$ using $N$, then I take the maximum value of them and add it to a list, and then repeat that process many times, the distribution that represents the values on that list are what I want $M_3$ to represent, I would imagine such a distribution would have a "peak" of some sort, something a cumulative distribution does not.

Comment: ?? Cumulative distribution functions are **never** [unimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality#Unimodal_probability_distribution) since these are nondecreasing. But yes, the PDF of each $M_n$ is unimodal.

Comment: What is the PDF of each $M_n$ then?

Comment: My first comment provides everything you need to compute it.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I figured it out, I appreciate all your help.

Comment: It has been over two months. Would you consider posting an answer and accept it yourself (self-answering is encouraged on the site), or deleting this question post to wrap it up? It seems that you have already got what you wanted here or elsewhere and have moved on.